# Create variable once

Tags: c#

Here is the following class I use.

removed

The problem is, here is my function to update my tooltip.

My question is, how can I edit the class file so instead of creating 'new Map()' every time the function tooltipUpdate is called, I can rather create it once in program.cs?

Comment: I might be misunstanding the question. If you create the map in the program.cs and pass it to the tooltip it should resolve your issue. There are other options like the singleton pattern, but it's probably best just to pass it to the tooltipupdate method.

Comment: I thought you were not supposed to inherit from `Dictionary<>` but from `KeyedCollection<>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your instance inside of your class. Put the definition outside of th `tooptipUpdate` method.

```
Map map = new Map();
public void tooltipUpdate(int m)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, map[m]);
}
```

Comment: @Andrew You gotta tick it if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the variable outside the scope of the function.

```
Map map = new Map();
public void tooltipUpdate(int m)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, map[m]);
}
```

Note, you cannot use the `var` keyword outside the scope of a method, so you need to explicitly state the type.  From the [var docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type var. An implicitly typed local
>   variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type
>   yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

Also, the [Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) documentation has good information on how the `var` keyword works and when it is legal to use `var`.

Comment: can we pass implicitly typed variables as function arguments? as OP did `toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, map[m]);`? here `map` is created using `var`.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi yes, the variable is still strongly typed and thus  any method calls that use the variable will be type checked and will fail compilation if they don't match the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't reckon `map` should change at a class level, make it `readonly` and instantiate it at the constructor.

```
private readonly Map map;

public MyClass()
{
    map = new Map();
}
```

Then,

```
public void tooltipUpdate(int m)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, map[m]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers are good answers, but I would recommend passing the map object to the method. So I'd move this:

```
    Map map = new Map();
```

to program.cs, or wherever you call the TooltipUpdate method and change tooltipupdate to this:

```
    public void tooltipUpdate(int m, Map map)
    {

        toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, map[m]);
    }
```

This is almost certainly better than declaring the map at the class level, properly inverting control to the calling method. For instance, you could have 2 map objects at the same time this way.